# Can Mockito doAnswer Intercepts Call Mocked Methods or is there an Interceptor that Can?

Tags: mockito

I need to write a unit test to show that a lock will turn away threads from a block of code when a service is already in use. (I realize that it is not possible to write unit tests for locks in the general case, I just need to provide a sanity check.)

The the test suite already relies heavily on mockito so the plan is to intercept a secondary call inside the controlled block of code and use the intercept to call the service again, as if from another thread. As follows:

```
public class MyService {    
    private AtomicBoolean isServiceRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public void runServiceIfNotAlreadyRunning() {
        if (!isServiceRunning.compareAndSet(false, true)) return;
        try {
            anotherService.doSomethingElse();
        } finally {
            int result = isServiceRunning.set(false);
        }
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTests {
   @Mock
   private AnotherService anotherService;

   @InjectMocks
   private MyService myService;

   @Test
   public void testServiceDoesNotExecuteOrBlockWhenAlreadyRunning() {
       myService.runServiceIfNotAlreadyRunning();

       doAnswer(invocation -> {
           myService.doSomething();
           return 5;
       }).when(anotherService.doSomethingElse());

       // verify()  ...
   }
}
```

However, this code yields a stubbing error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
>   Unfinished stubbing detected here:
>   -> at *"the doAnswer line"*)
>
> E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
>   Examples of correct stubbing:
>   ...

Likely because Mockito does not support calling a mock from doAnswer. Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: What's the stubbing error you're getting?

Comment: @SeamusR Good point.  I added the message to the description above.